# Неправильно вычисляется QGraphicsItem:: childBoundingRect()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Есть такой код:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QDebug>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        QGraphicsRectItem *r = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 0, 0);
        QGraphicsRectItem *r1 = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 20, 10, r);
        QGraphicsRectItem *r2 = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 20, 10, r);

        //qDebug() << r->childrenBoundingRect();                        
        r1->setPos(0, 10);
        qDebug() << r->childrenBoundingRect();

        QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        scene->addItem(r);

        QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
        view->setScene(scene);

        setCentralWidget(view);
    }
};
```

Как видите, одна строка в нем закомментирована. В таком состоянии в отладочной консоли появляется текст:

```
QRectF(0,0 20x20)
```

Стоит раскоментировать строку `//qDebug() << r->childrenBoundingRect();` и вывод изменится на:

```
QRectF(0,0 20x10) 
QRectF(0,0 20x10)
```

Так как метод `childrenBoundingRect` константный, я ожидал увидеть

```
QRectF(0,0 20x10) 
QRectF(0,0 20x20)
```

Может кто-нибудь объяснить это поведение и предложить как с этим бороться?

Comment: Вероятно, внутри используется какое-то кэширование на `mutable` членах. Я бы предложил посмотреть в исходники Qt. И возможно отправив им баг-репорт по результатам. Ещё предложение: проверить всё это на более свежей версии.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что происходит в childrenBoundingRect():

```
QRectF QGraphicsItem::childrenBoundingRect() const
{
 if (!d_ptr->dirtyChildrenBoundingRect)
    return d_ptr->childrenBoundingRect;

 d_ptr->childrenBoundingRect = QRectF();
 d_ptr->childrenBoundingRectHelper(0, &d_ptr->childrenBoundingRect, 0); //вычисляется childrenBoundingRect
 d_ptr->dirtyChildrenBoundingRect = 0; // в следующий вызов условие в первой строчке всегда выполняется, возвращается уже вычисленный childrenBoundingRect
 return d_ptr->childrenBoundingRect;
}
```

Comment: Что происходит понятно. А как теперь с этим быть?

Comment: `setPos` по идее должен выставлять `d_ptr->dirtyChildrenBoundingRect` в отличное от нуля состояние.

Comment: QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

Comment: @alexolut, эту переменную меняет метод `setFlags`. Если "передернуть" флаг `ItemClipsChildrenToShape`, `childrenBoundingRect` вернет правильное значение

Comment: QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this); Вставьте перед вашими `qDebug`.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb так и `setPos` должен её дергать.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что мою проблему может решить метод `QGraphicsItem::prepareGeometryChange`.

```
    qDebug() << r->childrenBoundingRect();   //QRectF(0,0 20x10) 
    r1->prepareGeometryChange();
    r1->setPos(0, 10);
    qDebug() << r->childrenBoundingRect();   //QRectF(0,0 20x20)
```

Этот код мог бы сработать если бы `prepareGeometryChange` не находился в секции `protected`. Но так как я все равно наследуюсь в основном коде от `QGraphicsItem`, вызвать его проблем не составляет.

Ну или можно написать `#define protected public` :)

Comment: А почему SetPos не устанавливает нужное значение флага не удалось понять?

Comment: @alexolut, возможно значение это флага меняет какой-нибудь эвенет, который приходит от сцены. Если сначала поместить все итемы на сцену, а потом менять позицию, то все работает правильно

Comment: т.е. ответ awesome про сцену имеет смысл? Может дело в не правильном понимании архитектурных принципов и сцена должна быть всегда?

Comment: @alexolut, это невозможно если какой-нибудь `QGraphicsItem` создает в конструкторе дочерние итемы(что у меня в основном коде как раз и происходит).

Comment: @alexolut, я почти угадал на счет сцены. Отрывок кода из `setPos`:     `if (scene) q->prepareGeometryChange();`